# Ebean ManyToOne Mapping CRUD

Tags: jpa, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two Entities Transaction and Category with ManyToOne mapping. So many transaction can fall into have category.

```
@Entity
class Transaction extends Model{
  @Id 
  public Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="cat_id")
  public Category cat;
}

@Entity
class Category extends Model{

 @Id
 @Column(name="cat_id")
 public Long catId;

 @Column(unique=true)     
 public String catName;

 @ManyToOne
 public List<Transaction> transactions

}
```

Now, when I add two transactions with same catName twice, it throws Unique constraint failure on catName. Is there any way I can instruct Ebean to merge Category, if CatName already exists (instead of always trying to insert)?

Also is this mapping approach correct, considering following:
  If I delete Transaction, corresponding Category should not be deleted as it may be referenced by other Transactions.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have wrong annotation on `Category` model. If you want to list all `Transaction` data corresponded to any `Category` data. You should mark this with `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`. As you marked your `Transaction` relation with `Category` as **Many-To-One relationship**, meaning that every `Transaction` has **one** `Category` associated to.

```
// This means every transaction has exactly one category associated 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="cat_id")
public Category cat;
```

The relationship between `Category` with `Transaction` should be **One-To-Many**. The code below is a guidance how to fix your model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name="cat_id")
    public Long catId;

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String catName;

    // This means one category can have many transaction associated
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat")
    public List<Transaction16507336> transactions;
}
```

It should allow you to save different `Transaction` object with same `Category`. Hope it is useful for you friend. :)

---

#### Update

The `Category` and `Transaction` model now have bi-directional relationship, this means if you have `Category` object you can also have `Transaction` object associated to, and vice versa. To save your model, you can follow this approach :

```
Category cat1 = Ebean.find(Category.class, 1L); // fetch category that exsist 
Transaction t1 = new Transaction(); // this is new transaction
t1.cat = cat1; // cat1 category
t1.save();
Transaction t2 = new Transaction(); // this is new transaction
t2.cat = cat1; // cat1 category
t2.save();
```

---

> **Note:** [This reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) may useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Wayan, I fixed that after finding the reference you mentioned. However there is another problem, when I add another transaction with same CatId and CatName, I get PK violation on catId. I guess EBean isn't smart enough to merge in case to ManyToOne relationship from Transaction to Category. A solution I used is to fetch the Categorgy before saving transaction, and then save transaction. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Every `new SomeModel()` expression always tell Ebean to make new record, so if you assign your newly created `Category` even it is already on database, Ebean always try to insert the record. And.. Yeah friend, your approach is correct. Have a good day for you.

Comment: Sorry for ask something unrelated here, I'm just new to Ebean and feel strange for the way it persists entity. 
Say, I'm forced to fetch first if I wanna create a transaction of a category, and the overhead is unnecessary considering underlying sql table needs only category's id. 
Let me know if I'm wrong plz, i just cannot understand it, thx for your help!